# browser-window-shared-view-cube-rotation-animation

Tags: reactjs, next.js

**browser-window-shared-view-cube-rotation-animation**

```html
'use client';

import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function ClientSideComponent () {

  const [windowDetails, setWindowDetails] = useState({
    windowX: 0,
    windowY: 0,
    screenWidth: 0,
    screenHeight: 0,
  });

  const [divSize, setDivSize] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });

  const contentRef = useRef(null);

  const updateWindowDetails = () => {

    setWindowDetails({
      windowX: window.screenX,
      windowY: window.screenY,
      screenWidth: window.screen.availWidth,
      screenHeight: window.screen.availHeight,
    });

    requestAnimationFrame(updateWindowDetails);
  };

  useEffect(() => {

    document.body.style.cssText = 'margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;';

    requestAnimationFrame(updateWindowDetails);

    // Update div size after the component has mounted
    if (contentRef.current) {
      setDivSize({
        width: contentRef.current.clientWidth,
        height: contentRef.current.clientHeight,
      });
    }

    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(updateWindowDetails);
    };
  }, []);

  // option 2
  const { windowX, windowY, screenWidth, screenHeight } = windowDetails;

  const contentWidth = divSize.width;
  const contentHeight = divSize.height;

  const screenCenterX = screenWidth / 2;
  const screenCenterY = screenHeight / 2;

  const contentX = screenCenterX - (contentWidth / 2);
  const contentY = screenCenterY - (contentHeight);

  return (
    <div>

      <div
        ref={contentRef}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          transform: `translate(${-(windowX - contentX)}px, ${-(windowY - contentY)}px)`,
          whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        }}
      >
        <p>windowX: {windowX}</p>
        <p>windowY: {windowY}</p>
        <br />
        <p>screenWidth: {screenWidth}</p>
        <p>screenHeight: {screenHeight}</p>
        <br />
        <p>contentWidth: {contentWidth}</p>
        <p>contentHeight: {contentHeight}</p>
        <br />
        <p>contentWidth: {contentWidth}</p>
        <p>contentHeight: {contentHeight}</p>


      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default ClientSideComponent;
```

The code above is an attempt at the fixed content to screen and open multiple browser windows to which the content looks like it is in the same relative position.

To run this create a React or Next JS app, make a component, and render only it on a page.

It is supposed to be dead center on the screen but it is a bit off on the Y. Can you help explain why and provide a fix?

Using const contentY = screenCenterY - (contentHeight /2); makes it even more decentered.

Based on the values it should be dead center but it is not.

**Update (01/21/2024):**

Solved the issue by accounting for the browser's header (search bar, tabs area, favorite tabs and other such) with:

`centerY: (window.screen.height / 2) - (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight),`

Here is a repo with the final version, code, and semi-detailed explanation comments:

*https://github.com/Alex-Kamenev/browser-window-shared-view-cube-rotation-animation/blob/main/src/components/ClientSideComponent.jsx*

Here is a live version of the app:

*https://browser-window-shared-view-cube-rotation-animation-dcivykt6n.vercel.app/*

**Key Note:**
***The current implementation only works correctly when the browser zoom level is set to 100%***

**Result - Multiple browser windows shared animation:**
[image: multiple browser windows shared position and animation of object]

Comment: Alright, after some more investigating here is what I was missing: Accounting for the browser's header (search bar, favorites tap, and so on). The way I ended up accounting for is with:

     centerY: (window.screen.height / 2) - (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight),